# redis: setting 'maxclients' on the fly

Tags: configuration, redis

How do you set `maxclients` to `X` in redis?  I know that it should look something like this:

`config set maxclients X`

but I keep getting the follow errors

`(error) ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: maxclients`

I even checked to make sure that `maxclients` is supported by `config set` by running `config get *` and `maxclients` *is* listed, its number `55` in the huge list printed out by `config get *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, despite the fact that the official Redis [documentation](http://redis.io/commands/config-set) says that anything supported by *config get* is supported by *config set*, *config set* does, in fact, **not** support the [maxclients](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/464) parameter, and will not support it **until** version **2.8**, I believe.

Comment: is it supported now?

Comment: @ealeon I don't think so.  Version 2.8 still isn't out and while the ticket requesting `CONFIG SET` has been closed I don't think that the branch or  pull request where the change was implemented has been merged back into master yet, but there's no real way to tell since they didn't tag the issue # when they committed the implementation.